# HttpUtility does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I get this error when compiling a C# application. Looks like a trivial error, but I can't get around it.

My setup is Windows 7 64 bit. Visual-Studio 2010 C# express B2Rel.

I added a reference to System.Web.dll located at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0`, but it has a yellow exclamation symbol and I still get the above error. I also have the `using System.Web` declaration.

What am I doing wrong?

---

**Update:** After getting the prompt answer pointing me at the root cause, I searched a bit in Google to where it states that System.Web.dll is for the full framework. I did not find such a reference.
For newbies like me, [**this**](http://blogs.msdn.com/jgoldb/archive/2009/10/19/what-s-new-in-net-framework-4-client-profile-beta-2.aspx) blog summarizes the difference between the frameworks (client and full) nicely. I could not find a spot that says whether a certain Dll is supported in the client framework or not. I guess the exclamation mark in Visual Studio should be the first signal...

Comment: Are you targeting the Client Profile?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You're probably targeting the Client Profile, in which `System.Web.dll` is not available.

You can target the full framework in project's *Properties*.

Comment: Bingo! where is that specified? Where was I supposed to read this? Thanks.

Comment: I've set full framework in Project Properties, yet the problem exists.

Comment: @AlexJolig: Make sure you have the reference and the namespace.

Comment: @blackholeearth0_gmail: What's the problem? What are you targetting?

Comment: i converted project from .net2 to .net4.  just changing Target Framework didnt' fix problem. i needed to add the dll,  too.  that is explained better  in at lxk613's answer ,  and shows what i need to do  to fix the problem .

Answer (score 209):

You need to add the `System.Web` reference;

1. Right click the "Reference" in the Solution Explorer
2. Choose "Add Reference"
3. Check the ".NET" tab is selected.
4. Search for, and add "System.Web".

Comment: VS2012 Console App using targeting .NET Framework 4.5. This resolved.

Comment: Even with the target, only adding reference worked for me. Thanks lxk613

Comment: My solution Explorer tree does not contain "Reference"

Comment: if you are using Azure functions, add #r "System.Web" on top of your file

Answer (score 18):

SLaks has the right answer... but let me be a bit more specific for people, like me, who are annoyed by this and can't find it right away :

Project -> Properties -> Application -> Target Framework -> select ".Net Framework 4"

the project will then save and reload.

Comment: I had the error even WITH the full framework targeted! Adding System.Web.dll as a reference worked though.

Comment: And obviously make sure to add `System.Web` or `System.Web.Mvc` to the file in question too.

Answer (score 15):

> In order to resolve this, Kindly go to the below path
>
> Project-->Properties-->Application-->TargetFramework
>
> and change the Framework to ".NET Framework 4".
>
> Once you do this, the project will close and re-open.
>
> This should solve the error

(but for some reason @Karan Modi's answer does not...)

next right-click the references tab in the solution explorer and choose add reference,

choose "System.Web"

(declaring the namespace directly by "using System.Web;" doesnt seems to be enough...you have to add it to the solution explorer...i cant understand why - which is no surprise because i am a cobol programmer..

Answer (score 12):

After following the answers above , and did

> Project -> Properties -> Application -> Target Framework -> select
>   ".Net Framework 4"

It still didn't work until I went to 
 `Project -> Add Reference` 
And selected `System.web`.
And everything worked link a charm.

Comment: Same solution has already been provided by someone, 2 years back. Please check the solutions before posting your own. The question is too old and the original poster is less likely to notice your response.

Comment: Seems like @lxk613's answer

Answer (score 8):

In order to resolve this, Kindly go to the below path

Project-->Properties-->Application-->TargetFramework

and change the Framework to ".NET Framework 4".

Once you do this, the project will close and re-open.

This should solve the error.

Comment: on Mac, Target Framework max (thanks to mono) is .NET 2. How can I solve on there?

Answer (score 4):

Agrega System.web a las referencias del proyecto.

[Edit]

According to Google Translate, this translates to:

> Add System.Web to the project references.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a reference to Sysem.Web.Dll did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem what I did, I copied web.dll from Microsoft.NET framework, then paste in root of project, then add dll refrence to app, it worked

Answer (score 0):

It worked for by following  process:

Add Reference:

```
system.net
system.web
```

also, include the namespace

```
using system.net
using system.web
```