# mono missing HttpUtility on OS X?

Tags: c#, macos, mono

## Problem

I freshly installed mono on OS X Lion, compiled and ran my first-ever csharp "hello world", and then attempted a web request...

But I'm missing HttpUtility.

```
gmcs GoogleExample.cs -r:System.Web.Services -r:System.Web 
GoogleExample.cs(14,32): error CS0103: The name `HttpUtility' does not exist in the current context
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings
```

What to do?

## History

I code C, NodeJS, Python, Ruby, etc. No noob to programming, just to mono.

I just installed mono (MRE Runtime, MDK, and MonoDevelop) on OS X via these instructions: http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html

Then I went off to play hello world with these instructions:
http://www.mono-project.com/Mono_Basics

And now I want to create a web request following this tutorial:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cross-platform/introtomono1.aspx?msg=3229009

End Goal:
Naturally, I want to create a JSON-based chat server as my first csharp project.

Comment: Mono is certainly not missing HttpUtility. But maybe your install is. Try installing the Mono SDK, you'll have better luck at writing programs with a SDK than with a runtime.

Comment: I do have the MDK installed. I believe that's what installed `gmcs` in the first place. Is there another SDK not listed on that downloads page I should be looking for?

Comment: are you sure you're not missing a `using` statement in your program? could we take a look at your code?

Comment: It's on the codeproject tutorial link. I just copy/pasted `GoogleExample.cs`. I was just looking on another SO post and it mentions that there's a difference between "Client" and "Full" frameworks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405182/httputility-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context. Perhaps this is related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently google couldn't find it either, so they wrote there own api-compatible version:

Here's a workaround:

1. Compile Google's version as a library

   ```
   wget 'http://google-gdata.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/clients/cs/src/core/HttpUtility.cs'
   gmcs -t:library HttpUtility.cs
   ```
2. Edit `GoogleExample.cs` to include that namespace

   ```
   using Google.GData.Client; // where HttpUtility lives
   ```
3. Recompile using the library

   ```
   gmcs GoogleExample.cs -r:System.Web.Services -r:System.Web -r:HttpUtility
   ```

Side Note: the RegEx (or perhaps URL) in the example `GoogleExample.cs` is out of date, so it never returns results, but at least it compiles and runs.

Comment: Yeah, but why take a dependency on the whole GData API when the stuff is right there in the framework?

Comment: Look over the code and comments. It appears to be an exact duplicate of Mono's System.Web.HttpUtility, nothing to do with the GData API other than the namespace.

Answer (score 0):

I just started a new ASP.Net solution in Monodevelop 2.6

Typing `Http` in the codebehind (`button1Clicked`) of the sample page, immediately autocompletes to HttpUtility, among many others.

This is certainly not missing. You need reference to

```
System.Web
```

though

Comment: What OS are you on and can you build the same app with xbuild and gmcs?

Comment: Linux and/or Windows, yes I can build that from the command line too: `gmcs /out:Test.dll /t:library /r:System.dll /r:System.Web.dll /r:System.Web.Services.dll Global.asax.cs Default.aspx.cs Default.aspx.designer.cs`