# Im getting error on visual studio 2010: The type or namespace name 'HttpUtility' does not exist

Tags: c#, winforms

How can i solve it ?
If im doing in my code: using System.Web; it dosent help
I tried ot add reference of System.Web.ApplicationServices didnt help also tried to reference: 
System.WebServices Didnt help either. This is the only two references that are using Web i have in the visual studio 2010 .net references list.

The line is:

```
var queryString = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(url);
```

The error is on the: HttpUtility

Error   1   The type or namespace name 'HttpUtility' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

The project is set on Target Framework to: .net 4 client profile. I have windows 8 64bit.

Comment: doublecheck you really wrote it correct. also it should be possible to leave out System.Web as you already imported it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HttpUtility does not exist in the current context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405182/httputility-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The project is set on Target Framework to: .net 4 client profile.

That's the problem. [`HttpUtility`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.aspx) doesn't exist in the client profile. Target the full profile instead (and make sure you have a reference to `System.Web.dll`).

Compare the "Version information" line from the above documentation:

> .NET Framework
>   Supported in: 4.5, 4, 3.5, 3.0, 2.0, 1.1, 1.0

with that of (say) `System.String`:

> .NET Framework
>   Supported in: 4.5, 4, 3.5, 3.0, 2.0, 1.1, 1.0
>   .NET Framework Client Profile
>   Supported in: 4, 3.5 SP1
>   Portable Class Library
>   Supported in: Portable Class Library
>   .NET for Windows Store apps
>   Supported in: Windows 8

Comment: @DoronMuzar: When you've targeted the full .NET 4 framework, did you make sure you had a reference to System.Web.dll? If so, it really should be fine.