# The name 'HttpUtility' does not exist in the current context (winform)

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

Iget the following error:

> The name 'HttpUtility' does not exist in the current context

I am building a `winform` app this my code using `framework 4 client profile`
and I can't find the `System.Web` reference:

```
string longurl = "https://test.com/currentaccount/Pages/current.aspx";
                        var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(longurl);
                        var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uriBuilder.Query);//error
                        query["ltFrom"] = FromDate;
                        query["ltTo"] = ToDate;
                        query["ltFilterSelected"] = "none";
                        uriBuilder.Query = query.ToString();
                        longurl = uriBuilder.ToString();
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HttpUtility` cannot be accepted with ClientProfile - change your .Net version to full.

Answer (score 3):

The project is set on Target Framework to: .net 4 client profile.

That's the problem. `HttpUtility` doesn't exist in the client profile. Target the full profile instead (and make sure you have a reference to `System.Web.dll`).

Compare the "Version information" line from the above documentation:

.NET Framework

```
Supported in: 4.5, 4, 3.5, 3.0, 2.0, 1.1, 1.0
```

with that of (say) System.String:

.

```
NET Framework
Supported in: 4.5, 4, 3.5, 3.0, 2.0, 1.1, 1.0
.NET Framework Client Profile
Supported in: 4, 3.5 SP1
Portable Class Library
Supported in: Portable Class Library
.NET for Windows Store apps
Supported in: Windows 8
```

ref: [Im getting error on visual studio 2010: The type or namespace name 'HttpUtility' does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19864390/im-getting-error-on-visual-studio-2010-the-type-or-namespace-name-httputility)

Answer (score 2):

to use "HttpUtility" simply add reference in visual studio from option Project->Add Reference->click on system.web then ok.

Answer (score 1):

`HttpUtility` is based in System.Web, the Client Profile for .NET 4 only allows access to a subset of the .NET framework and System.Web is not included in that.

If you can, change from Client Profile to Full unless you have a really good reason to stick with Client Profile in which case you will need to find a different approach.