# Call HttpUtility from within Azure Functions

Tags: c#, .net, rest, azure, azure-functions

I am trying to make a REST call from within Azure Functions. For these lines of code:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
```

I get the following error.

```
The name 'HttpUtility' does not exist in the current context
```

I am using the web interface in Azure.com.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are probably missing a proper reference to `System.Web`:

```
#r "System.Web"
using System.Web;
```

See [Referencing External Assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#referencing-external-assemblies).

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, I have the proper references. This post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405182/httputility-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context is close, but I do not know how to specify the full framework in Azure Functions.

Comment: Function App always targets full framework... I have your code compiling successfully in my function...

Comment: Thanks @Mikhail, can you explain the #r "System.Web" or link to some documentation

Comment: @Ryan Added the link